# CSS font override issue / trouble with google webfont?

Tags: css

My problem is simple, I have the font set in the body style to a google webfont:

```
body {
  font: normal 100% 'Poiret One', 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
  color: Grey;
  ...
}
```

And then later on I want to set the text within a class to Trebuchet MS

```
#currentpage_content {
  font: 'Trebuchet Ms', Sans-Serif;
  color: red;
  ...
}
```

The result, is that the color on the text in `#currentpage_content` is right (it's red) but the font is definitely still 'Poiret One'. **The font doesn't seem to change from `'Poiret One'` to `'Trebuchet MS'` .** I also swapped things around a bit, making Trebuchet MS the default but I had the same problem just reversed (Everything was Trebuchet MS even when I set many class fonts to Poiret One.)

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `font-family` instead of just `font`

```
font-family: 'Trebuchet Ms', Sans-Serif;
```

or specify all the required parameters for `font`

```
font: normal 100% 'Trebuchet Ms', Sans-Serif;
```

Answer (score 1):

try using "font-family" instead of just "font."
also, just in case, use double quotations instead of single.

some good debugging tools and resources for css are:

- firebug, which is a plugin for firefox
- http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/
- http://css-tricks.com/

best of luck!
and keep asking questions. that's the best way to learn.